# Capacitor transparent status bar overlapping with toolbar in Ionic app for android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I set a transparent status bar in my app.component.html in my ionic app for android as follows:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StatusBar,Style } from "@capacitor/status-bar";
import { Storage } from "@capacitor/storage";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public router:Router
  ) {}
  async shouldShowStarterScreen(){
    let hasSeenScreen = await Storage.get({key:"seenScreen"});
    if(hasSeenScreen.value == null){
      this.router.navigate(["starter-screen"]);
    }
  }
  slideOpts = {

  }
  async ngOnInit(){
    this.shouldShowStarterScreen();
  /*  await StatusBar.setStyle({style:Style.Dark})
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({
      color:"#3F00FF"
    })*/
    StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({overlay:true});
  }
}
```

Its working but there is a slight overlap of the status bar on the app as seen below
[image]

What is a quick, suitable way of correcting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want keep overlay, then you can update styles for your toolbar globally in `global.scss`:

```
ion-header.md {
    ion-toolbar:first-child {
        --padding-top: 27px;
        height: 66px;
    }
}
```

This styles suitable for header like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
            First title
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            Second title
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

This style is needed only for Android and only for the first toolbar in your `ion-header`. If you will use pages without `ion-header` (or with another `ion-header` structure) you should update your styles in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks so much this worked, youre a life saver. But on a side note, is there anyway of using safe-area-insets with capacitor for android

Comment: @NobleEugene yes, you can use `var(--ion-safe-area-top)` for example in your styles. More info here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced

Comment: I just literally did `--ion-safe-area-top: 27px;` to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to record another approach.

Another simple way to do this would be to add ionic's _forceStatusbarPadding property to app.modules.

Here you can find a complete overlay example.
https://github.com/heliomarpm/ionic-transparent_statusbar_demo

[Imagem do exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVF8f.png)